# Provide javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword from file (docker swarm setup) instead of environment property

Tags: java, docker, ssl, docker-compose, openssl

I would like to inject a Truststore password to `javax.net` from a docker secret in a docker swarm setup.

Currently I have:

```
service-1:
  image: service-1:${BUILD_VERSION:-latest}
  deploy:
    mode: global
  environment:
    - JAVA_OPTS=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/run/secrets/truststore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit # <=== this is what I would like to change!


# later:
secrets:
  truststore:
    file: /opt/docker-secrets/trust-store.ts
  truststore_pwd:
    file: /opt/docker-secrets/trust-store-pwd.ts
```

Any ideas, on how to get rid of the line starting with JAVA_OPT (especially the parameter `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword` and to integrate this as a secret as well?

Thanks!